# How to input a custom expression for a function?

Tags: ocaml

Is there any way that when you run the code you can choose the expression of a function let's say f x instead of writing it down before you run the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no simple way in OCaml to execute code that is determined at runtime. It's a statically compiled language.

With some effort you could run the OCaml compiler from your code, then load the result as a shared library. Or you could link the OCaml interpreter into your program.

IMHO it is usually a bad plan to execute code that is produced dynamically. It gives the program awesome power, but is extremely difficult to control (and to understand).